# RxJava: Blocking on an observable after subscription?

Tags: multithreading, system.reactive, rx-java, rx-android, rx-scala

I have a special need for an observable.

Usually, my observables run in a different thread. But, sometimes they need to block another thread in the middle of subscription. Something the way a future behaves.

An example:

```
val o = Observable.create(/* computation */)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .observeOn(/* current thread */);

val s = o.subscribe(/* subscriber */);`
```

Suddenly, an event happens on yet another thread that signals the current thread that it should wait for the execution of the subscription `s`. (An example would be Android's `onPause`.)

How do I do that? How do I wait on the subscription `s` and even possibly retrieve all of the results?

(Subjects?)

Comment: `o.toBlocking()` is kind of equivalent to `future.get()`

Comment: @VladimirMironov yes but that is *before* I subscribe to the observable. What I need is after subscription. So basically, no double computations.

Comment: Maybe a serialized ReplaySubject could do the trick. Essentially you convert the subject to an Observable, and then that to a blocking one... or subscribe to that observable on the immediate thread.

Comment: ... or take care to cache the results in the original observable, and then just subscribe on the immediate thread.

Comment: I see there is an `Observable#cache()` method. That is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this seems to be:

1. Make the observable be a caching one with `Observable#cache()`. (If your observable is a stream of values, use an appropriate Subject and use that as the observable.)
2. Subscribe to the cached observable / subject.
3. When the event occurs, simply subscribe to the cached observable / subject on the thread(s) you require. Cancel the subscription as appropriate.